# Linear map from random V to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

If:
$$
f: V \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}, f \neq0
$$
a)Show that there is $v \in V$ such that $f(v) = 1$

b) Show that $V = \text{ker}(f) \oplus[V]$

For a)
$$
\exists w \in V : f(w) = a \neq 0\\
v = a^{-1} w\\
f(v) = f(a^{-1}w) = a^{-1}f(w) = \frac{a}{a} = 1
$$

For b)
$$
\dim \text{im}(f) = \mathbb{R} = 1\\
\dim \text{ker}(f) = V - 1\\
\dim [\text{ker}(f) \oplus[V]] = V-1+1 = V
$$

Am I correct?!

Is it ok to assume that $v = a^{-1}w$ in a?!

Thanks!

Comment: How do we know that $f$ is not the zero map?  Is your question missing an assumption?

Comment: "Is it ok to assume that v=a−1w in a?!"

You are not assuming, you are *defining* $v$.

Comment: @AustinChristian, I forgot to write it! Sorry. I'll edit it

Comment: @user8960 Yeah, sorry about that... Is it ok to define v the way I defined it?!